# Scroll down the page to get all the elements in JS puppeter

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm using code to get the elements and it works perfectly and takes what I need. However, I realize that he does not pick up all the elements as he lacks loading them on the screen, and to load I need to scroll down.

I searched but found no way to scroll down to load the other elements, can someone help me?

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const acesso = require('./acesso');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto('https://www.instagram.com/')
  await page.waitFor('input[name="username"]')
  await page.type('input[name="username"]', acesso.dados.usuario, { delay: 100 })
  await page.type('input[name="password"]', acesso.dados.senha, { delay: 100 })
  await page.keyboard.press('Enter')
  await page.waitForNavigation()
  await page.click('#react-root > section > main > div > div > div > div > button')
  await page.waitFor(10000)
  await page.click('.aOOlW.HoLwm')
  await page.goto('https://www.instagram.com/teamcarrascoo/')
  await page.waitFor(10000)
  await page.click('.RR-M-.h5uC0')
  await page.waitFor(1000)
  await page.click('.Igw0E.rBNOH.eGOV_._4EzTm')
  page.waitFor(2000)
  const hrefs = await page.$$eval('.xLCgt a', links => links.map(link => link.href));
  hrefs.forEach((link, index) =>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
    page.goto(link)
  },index * 10000)
  })
})();

//The problem is in const hrefs = await page.$$eval('.xLCgt a', links => links.map(link => link.href)); I need to get all the elements, but only what was loaded on the screen comes, so I need to scroll it.
```

Comment: I still have a problem. Well the following ... With the command below:
window.scrollBy (0, window.innerHeight)

It scrolls the page completely, however, I want the story bar, not the page.

If I close the story and use the command it works, however, when I open the story viewers my scroll bar (up and down) does not work with the command. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a two part problem.

1. How do you scroll down?

Use `window.scrollBy(0,window.innerHeight)` - This triggers the next page loading on instagram (verified)

2. How do you know you have reached the end?

keep recording the last known `scrollY` and if it doesn't change, you have reached the end.

Comment: I still have a problem. Well the following ... With the command below: window.scrollBy (0, window.innerHeight) It scrolls the page completely, however, I want the story bar, not the page. If I close the story and use the command it works, however, when I open the story viewers my scroll bar (up and down) does not work with the command. Can you help me with this?

Comment: You want scrolling horizontally on the story bar ?

Comment: No, top down story

Comment: I am still not clear on what you need, may i suggest you do a quick  screen recording of the behavior you are expecting ? Also, if closing the story bar and applying the `scrollBy` meets your needs, maybe hide it using `display:none` ? -

An additional thing i noticed is you are using style classes that may not stay valid through different builds, e.g: these are dynamic classes - `.xLCgt a` etc.